# How to get error being returned by FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Tags: php, arrays, validation, email, filter

I am currently working in php. My current form is supposed to generate some criteria for an email template.  It has a To, CC, and BCC field.  My current code for "To" works fine.  I then wanted to validate multiple emails at once.  For example, if someone entered example@example.com, test@test.com, etc.. I would want it to examine each one.  For some reason it is throwing an error.  Below is my current php.  I wanted to know if there was a way I could see what the error was.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
$errTo = $_POST['To'];
$errCC = $_POST['CC'];
$errBCC = $_POST['BCC'];
function died() 
{
$error = false;
return $error;
}
```

**I run into my problem here**

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')
{
if(filter_var($errTo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    if(isset($errCC))
    {
        $errCC = explode(",", $errCC);
        $count = count($errCC);
        for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i)
        {
            $errCC[$i] = str_replace(" ", "",$errCC[$i]);
            echo $errCC[$i];
            if(!filter_var($errCC[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $error = died();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no error returned. It either returns false if it is not an email address or the email address

Comment: I understand it either returns false or it returns the email.  What I'm asking is whether or not there is a way to return an explanation for why it failed.  For example, in a mysql query one could use code:      $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

Comment: It always fails for the same reason: the value passed is not a valid e-mail address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will always return false on failure, you therefore need to handle the reason yourself. The reason is always that its not a valid email address. It will not tell you `This email is missing a @ symbol`.

```
$errors = array();
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')
{
    // Check the to field and add it to the error array if its wrong
    if(!filter_var($errTo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
       $errors[] = $errTo;
    }

    if(isset($errCC))
    {
      $errCC = explode(",", $errCC);
      $count = count($errCC);
      for($i=0; $i<$count; ++$i)
      {
          $errCC[$i] = str_replace(" ", "",$errCC[$i]);
          echo $errCC[$i];
          if(!filter_var($errCC[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
          {
              // Add to our array the invalid emails
              $errors[] = $errCC[$i];
          }
      }
    }

    // Check if we have any invalid emails    
    if(count($errors))
    {
      // Display each email, remember to strip out 'badness' if you are outputting user variable to the browser
      foreach($errors as $err)
      {
          echo strip_tags($err) . " is not an email address<br />";
      }
    }
}
```